# Which design pattern is good to achieve run tiime polymorphism in this case?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, object-oriented-analysis

Following is the hierarchy to consider

```
                               Device
                                  ^
                                  |
                                  |
                            -------------
                            |           |
                            |           |
                       Television   AirConditioner
```

we have another class `Remote` to control the Devices.

**Approach 1**

```
class Remote 
{    
     Device* d; 
     public:
     Remote(Device* d){
        this->d = d;
     }

     void switchOn(){ 
          d->on();
     }
     //other methods 
};


//Simple classes for concept only.

class Device
{
    public: 
       virtual void on() = 0;
};
class Television : public Device
{
    public:
       void on(){
           cout << "television is turned on";
       }
       //other methods.
};
class AirConditioner : public Device
{
    public:
        void on(){
            cout << "Ac is turned on";
        }
};

int main(){

    Device *tv = new Television();
    Device *ac = new AirConditioner();

    Remote TVremote(tv); //assigning tv to the TVremote.
    Remote ACremote(ac); //assigning ac to the ACremote.
    TVremote.switchOn();
    ACremote.switchOn();

    return 0;
 }
```

The above program is self explanatory, where we are taking the advantage of run time polymorphism.

In the above program we bind the `Television` and `AirConditioner` object to `Remote` through `Device*` that is we are saying `Remote` **has-a** `Device` associated with it.

**Approach 2**

This is the approach which came to my mind at first step that is

`Device` **has-a** `Remote`
So, this leads to following

```
class Remote 
{    

     public:
     void switchOn(Device* d){ 
         d->on();
     }
     //other methods 
};


//Simple classes for concept only.

class Device
{
    private:
       Remote r;

    public: 
        Device(Remote* r){

              this->r = *r;
        }

       virtual void on() = 0;
};
class Television : public Device
{
    public:

       Television(Remote* r): Device(r){}
       void on(){
           cout << "television is turned on";
       }
       //other methods.
};
class AirConditioner : public Device
{
    public:
        AirConditioner(Remote* r): Device(r){}
        void on(){
            cout << "Ac is turned on";
        }
};

int main()
{
     Remote TvRemote;
     Remote AcRemote;

     Television* tv = new Television(TvRemote);
     AirConditioner* ac = new AirConditioner(AcRemote);

     TvRemote.switchOn(tv); //now we have to pass tv to the method although 
                            // Remote is of tv
     AcRemote.switchOn(ac); // same as above.


     return 0;
}
```

So I have following questions

**Q 1** When we have to program the above scenario the first thing which comes to human brain is `Television` **has-a** `Remote` (which is Approach 2) but when we implement it we need to pass `Remote` to the `Device` in the `Device` Constructor and also `Device` to the `switchOn()` method of the `Remote`, so we are unable to use the attachment of `Remote` and `Device` in the `Device` Constructor. How to get away with it?

So, what needs to be done here? Is approach 2 is better than the Approach 1? If yes, then what is the solution of above problem? If no then how do I satisfy myself that approach 1 is better?

I personally think (correct me if my view point is wrong) that `Television` **has-a** `Remote` is much more appealing than the other Approach.

Please help in deciding which approach is good?

**EDIT** One device is to be controlled with one Remote and vice-versa.

Comment: what are the actual constraints? Can one device be controlled by two different remotes? Is it possible to control two devices with the same remote?

Comment: ...can a remotes device change during its lifetime? Can a devices remote change during its lifetime? Once you answered this questions the design should be more or less clear.

Comment: @tobi303 I am just asking for a suggestion that which has-a relation to follow?

Comment: I dont really understand what is the difference between the two. If you just make the device register at the remote in its constructor there will be no need to pass the device when switching and the two approaches are more or less the same

Comment: anyhow you should do this. In the second example it is completely pointless for the devices to have a remote member, as you are not using it at all.

Comment: @tobi303 ya in approach 1 device pointer is used to invoke the on() method

Comment: I wouldn't read **"has a"** literally and match it with **"first thing which comes to human brain"**. In the scope of OOP I usually read "has a" as "has reference to a", "know about a", "has some relationship with a". Your 1st approach seems more logical to me

Comment: I agree with @tobi303 that the second approach is not even aware of the remote. I prefer the first approach. Plus I agree with mvidelgauz.

Comment: This cries for the visitor pattern imho.

Answer (score 2):

I think, your are overinterpreting the has-a relationship: When designing a system of classes that have to know each other, real-world analogies play virtually no role. The critical question is, which object needs to have access to which other objects in order to manipulate them / kick them into action. That is a purely technical question.

Coming back to your example: While a device usually has exactly one remote associated with it, it is not the device that needs to know which remotes can operate it. It is the remote that needs to kick the device into action (= call one of its methods). So the remote needs to know its device, not the device the remote.

So, I think you should just say that the remote has-a device which it controls. And leave it at that. If, and only if the device also needs to talk to the remote (unlikely), you can add to say that the device also has-a remote, in the same way as you add a second link to a linked list to form a double linked list. But you should not add that reference for no good reason at all.

Generally, if you let yourself be influenced by real world analogies too much, you get overcomplicated designs, which are bad. Always use the most simple and direct implementation that fits your needs (= follow the KISS principle). It's frequently the best one, anyway.

Comment: could you please suggest me some resources to read as I am used to look at any problem from real world viewpoint?

Comment: @Rouftantical Unfortunately, I can't. My source is my own programming experience, and only that. Frankly, I've never seen anyone comparing the benefits of real world analogies to those of analyzing technical requirements for class design. I guess, this is due to the fact that all good programmers are pragmatics in the end: They care about writing code that works, they don't care about following real world analogies. Rather they use those real world analogies to describe their thoughts/designs to others *as they see fit*. And if an analogy does not fit, it is ignored.